# Android show intent in Dialog

Tags: android

I am new to Android application development and I want to show an Intent as Dialog. How can I do this?

`Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`

I want to show this on dialog. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp4");  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");  
startActivity(intent);   

Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp3");  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `android:style/Theme.Dialog` in the corresponding activity in the manifest file.

Comment: i want to show Default intent like Camera intent,Gallery intent,Zoom Intent etc.How can i?pls suggest me